# Remove columns from data frame if any row contains a specific string

Tags: r

I would like to remove columns which contain the string `--` in any row.

```
Number  138 139 140 141 143 144 147 148 149 150 151 152 14  15  N…  
nm4804  A   B   --  A   B   A   A   --  A   A   A   A   A   --  A  
nm7574  B   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   --  A
nm8723  B   --  B   B   B   --  A   --  B   B   B   B   --  --  A
N…      B   A   A   A   A   B   A   --  A   A   B   --  --  --  A
```

I would like to count the -- frequency, if there is any column have more than 50% of -- in the columns, that column will be removed.

Desired result:

```
Number  138 140 141 143 147 149 150 151 N…  
nm4804  A   A   --    B A   A   A   A   A  
nm7574  B   A   A    A  A   A   A   A   A
nm8723  B   B   A    B  --    B  B  B   A
N…          B   A   A    A  A A A   B   A
```

**Data (thanks bgoldst)**

```
df <- data.frame(Number=c('nm4804','nm7574','nm8723','N…'),`138`=c('A','B','B','B'),`139`=c(
'B','A','--','A'),`140`=c('--','A','B','A'),`141`=c('A','A','B','A'),`143`=c('B','A','B','A'
),`144`=c('A','A','--','B'),`147`=c('A','A','A','A'),`148`=c('--','A','--','--'),`149`=c('A',
'A','B','A'),`150`=c('A','A','B','A'),`151`=c('A','A','B','B'),`152`=c('A','A','B','--'),
`14`=c('A','A','--','--'),`15`=c('--','--','--','--'),`N…`=c('A','A','A','A'),check.names=F,
stringsAsFactors=F);
```

Comment: It appears that your data uses `--` to indicate a missing value.  See `?read.table` and the argument `na.strings`.

Comment: I'm going to assume you want to remove the columns and not count anything, and will edit.  Roll back if that is not what you want.

Comment: You should give the problem a try first, then let us know where it is failing.

Comment: @Alos That is not necessary.  Clearly the community thinks that this problem is not valuable by the vote count, but an attempt by the questioner isn't going to help with that.

Comment: I would like to count number of -- because if one of the columns have more than 50% of -- , that column will be removed but I don't know how to do it . Thank you for your help .

Comment: @MatthewLundberg I respectfully disagree.  I feel that if he tried to solve the problem on his own first, then included his code, where it when wrong and what he desired as a result that would help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can also use `Filter`

```
Filter(function(x) !any(x=="--"), df1)
#    Number X138 X141 X143 X147 X149 X150 X151 N…
#1 nm4804    A    A    B    A    A    A    A  A
#2 nm7574    B    A    A    A    A    A    A  A
#3 nm8723    B    B    B    A    B    B    B  A
#4     N…    B    A    A    A    A    A    B  A
```

---

If we need to remove the columns with more than 50% of `--`

```
Filter(function(x) mean(x == '--') <= 0.5, df1)
```

NOTE: Based on the OP's example, all the columns will be retained here.

Comment: I would like to count number of -- because if one of the columns have more than 50% of -- , that column will be removed but I don't know how to do it . Thank you for your help .

Comment: @PeterChung  Updated with an option for the new case.

Comment: Almost there, What is function(x) ?

Comment: it is anonymous function

Answer (score 6):

Use [`colSums()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/colSums.html):

```
df[,colSums(df=='--')==0]
##   Number 138 141 143 147 149 150 151 N…
## 1 nm4804   A   A   B   A   A   A   A  A
## 2 nm7574   B   A   A   A   A   A   A  A
## 3 nm8723   B   B   B   A   B   B   B  A
## 4     N…   B   A   A   A   A   A   B  A
```

Comment: And to keep columns with less than 50% of `--` values, it would be `df[, colMeans(df == "--") < 0.5]`

Answer (score 1):

Since it is unclear in the question, I'm assuming that `nm4804` and such are row names, and `138..152` are column names, not actual data. With that, I'm guessing that this is a character matrix. Your data:

```
dat <- structure(c("A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "--", "A", "--", "A", 
"B", "A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "--", 
"B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "--", "A", "--", "--", "A", "A", "B", 
"A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "--", 
"A", "A", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "A", "A", "A", 
"A"), .Dim = c(4L, 15L), .Dimnames = list(c("nm4804", "nm7574", 
"nm8723", "N..."), c("138", "139", "140", "141", "142", "143", 
"144", "145", "146", "147", "148", "149", "150", "151", "152"
)))
```

Try this:

```
dat[,! apply(dat, 2, `%in%`, x = "--")]
#        138 141 142 144 146 147 148 152
# nm4804 "A" "A" "B" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A"
# nm7574 "B" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A"
# nm8723 "B" "B" "B" "A" "B" "B" "B" "A"
# N...   "B" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "B" "A"
```

Comment: Clearly `nm4804` and such are not row names, as there is a column name: `Number`.  Also, by the way the results are printed, my first guess would be that it is a data frame of factors/strings.

Comment: *Clearly*? Based on many questions with hand-typed tabulated numbers/letters, I wasn't certain if this was hand-made or not. Additionally, the code providing the data was added late in the game (I didn't have it available). It is *certainly* non-standard (though possible) to have numbers as column names, so I made a leap. Regardless, my code still works without change, so your comment was intended for what purpose?

Comment: Your code coerces to a matrix, where a matrix may not be the input.  If so, that's an unnecessary copy.  As for the purpose of my comment, it is to prod you to improve your answer.

Comment: Nope, it sure doesn't. Because of my assumptions, I *started* with a matrix, so my answer happily kept it as such. If you run it with a data.frame going in, it happily keeps it a data.frame. (Don't mistake the coersion going in inside the square brackets for what results outside of the square brackets.)

Comment: `if (is.object(X)) 
        X <- if (dl == 2L) 
            as.matrix(X)
        else as.array(X)` That is coercion to a matrix.  I didn't say the result was a matrix!  I said you were making an unnecessary copy.

Comment: Yes, and that code (from `apply`) returns a *vector* to the column-index component of the square brackets, which subsets `dat` into the same class it started as. It does not coerce `dat` in the end. Look, I appreciate the effort to try to get answers improved, but (1) I stated my assumptions, so the data I used should be justified even if my assumptions were later proved to be incorrect; and (2) my answer works equally well on both without changing my assumptions. I like both other answers (bgoldst, akrun) a little better than mine -- as do others (by upvotes), and I'm fine with that.

Comment: I must have misinterpreted you when you said *"your code coerces to a matrix"*. The comment of "unnecessary copy" is perfectly right, and I do prefer efficiency, thanks for the note.

Comment: Now you got me thinking ... it "must have been" hand-written (taken with a grain of salt): on my console, at least, data.frames with strings or factors both **right-justify** the cell contents, whereas this one is left-justified. Hah! (My assumptions are still wrong :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115571/discussion-between-matthew-lundberg-and-r2evans).

Comment: I would like to count number of -- because if one of the columns have more than 50% of -- , that column will be removed but I don't know how to do it . Thank you for your help .

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proposal using dplyr using the 'dat' dataframe proposed by @r2evans

```
dat <- structure(c("A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "--", "A", "--", "A", 
"B", "A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "--", 
"B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "--", "A", "--", "--", "A", "A", "B", 
"A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "--", 
"A", "A", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "A", "A", "A", 
"A"), .Dim = c(4L, 15L), .Dimnames = list(c("nm4804", "nm7574", 
"nm8723", "N..."), c("138", "139", "140", "141", "142", "143", 
"144", "145", "146", "147", "148", "149", "150", "151", "152"
)))
```

This enables to remove all columns containing more than 50% of '--'

```
dat %>% 
as.data.frame() %>% 
select_if(~!(sum(.=="--") / length(.) > 0.5))
```